# JavaScript ArcGIS: Update scene clipping area after creation

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clip, extents

I want to update (increase / decrease) scene clipping area after I create it. My goal is to give the user ability to adjust the clipping area. I am using scene view, if that's relevent.

I've managed to update the clipping area of the map using:

```js
const extent = view.clippingArea.clone();
view.clippingArea = extent.expand(0.5);
```

However when I try to set it to a specific range it does not want work:

```js
let extent = view.clippingArea.clone();
extent.extent.xmax = 1849093
extent.extent.xmin = 1488933
extent.extent.ymax = 5921967
extent.extent.ymin = 5688179

view.clippingArea = extent
```

How can I set clipping area to specific range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the spatial reference of the numbers you are using correct? You may want to create the extent and pass the spatialReference:

```
const extent = {
  // autocasts as new Extent()
  xmax: -10850000,
  xmin: -10920000,
  ymax: 4480000,
  ymin: 4440000,
  spatialReference: {
    // autocasts as new SpatialReference()
    wkid: 3857
  }
};
view.clippingArea = extent;
```

Comment: Spatial refrence is the same, so that shouldn't matter. However creating a new extent and assigning it to `view.clippingArea` seems to work.